# android mapview partly blank

Tags: android

There is a mapview in my application and it works well. I added a menu item, when click it,  a new activity that also has a mapview will start. Then finish the new activity and go back to the first one, part of the mapview become blank and never refresh when pan the map, and it can be recovered only after zooming in or zooming out several times. Did anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have mutliple mapviews in and Android application.  There are plenty of workarounds on here but imo its better to avoid it.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379575/how-to-use-multiple-mapactivities-mapviews-per-android-application-process).