# Android: Bottom of Google Maps gets black inside the application

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one Map on my main activity and It works fine. Recently I added another small map view on one of my sub activities using the same google map key. Now when I press back after looking at the map on sub activity, it returns to the main view and bottom of the map on main activity turns black. See the attached image. [image]

Is there anyone who has faced this problem and know why sometimes bottom of map turns balck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have 1 map activity per process.

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html

Comment: Have each Activity run in its own process.  Not to sure on how to acheive that though.  It may have been answered on Stackoverflow before because I have seen this problem asked before.

Comment: You got my curiosity going

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379575/how-to-use-multiple-mapactivities-mapviews-per-android-application-process