# How to use a single MapView across several MapActivities

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-fragments, mapactivity

I'm developing an app that shows a map on three different MapActivities.

To accomplish this I re-use a MapFragment across this three FragmentActivities which extend MapActivities using the [*Pete Doyle*'s port of the *Android Compatibility package*](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps).

The MapView used in this MapFragment is kept at the [Application Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

In order to avoid the *"this view already has a parent"* error, I remove the view from the current parent when opening a different activity:

```
ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) app.mapViewContainer.getParent();
if( null != parentViewGroup ) {
  parentViewGroup.removeView(app.mapViewContainer);
}
```

It all works well until the moment when i press the phone's back button and get to a previous MapActivity. At this time, the MapView is all black, since I removed it from its parent when changing activities, and the back button doesn't trigger a re-creation of the view...

I'm aware of this post:
[How to use multiple MapActivities/MapViews per Android application/process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379575/how-to-use-multiple-mapactivities-mapviews-per-android-application-process)

As a matter of fact, I got the idea to re-use the MapView across activities from the answer **Danny Remington - MacroSolve** gave.

I haven't tried to use multiple processes since I believe the solution I'm trying to implement is much lighter on resources.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my own problem...

When the MapFragment is being resumed I just had to remove all views from the fragment and from the mapview's parent, and then add the mapview to the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    resumed++;

    if (resumed > 0) {
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) this.getView();
        view.removeAllViews();

        ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) app.mapViewContainer.getParent();
        if (parentViewGroup != null) {
            parentViewGroup.removeAllViews();
        }

        view.addView(app.mapViewContainer);
    }
}
```