# Unexpected connection between two MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have two activities and each has a Mapview.  The problem is that when a Mapview changes its center or zoom the other one changes too. I’ve realized that each Mapview has a different id (in xml) and a different name variable. But the problem persist.

The code of each activity is too long to post here, because it implements a lot of functions. But I post the most significant part:

Activity  A)

```
    mapview_publish = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview_publish);
    mapview_publish.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapview_publish.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16); /
```

XML A)

```
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview_publish"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:apiKey="myapikey"
            android:clickable="false" />
```

Activity B)

```
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(20);
```

XML B)

```
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        style="@style/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:apiKey="myapikey"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: Show us the each activity's code.

Comment: could you explain how you resolve your problem(using your example)? I have the same problem between two mapview on different tab activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using multiple MapViews per process, it might conflict.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity

> Only one MapActivity is supported per process. Multiple MapActivities
>   running simultaneously are likely to interfere in unexpected and
>   undesired ways.

And also see my reply on [How to use multiple MapActivities/MapViews per Android application/process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379575/how-to-use-multiple-mapactivities-mapviews-per-android-application-process)

But as SpK commented, please provide the code of your activities.

Comment: I just realized that when you assign different processes to the activities that contained the maps it isn’t possible debug the app. Why? Even the debug perspective don't launch.

Comment: Eclipse? Or DDMS standalone? Did you run DDMS standalone? I don't use Eclipse, I use IntelliJ IDEA, or logcat directly. But not sure, haven't worked with different processes in one app for long time.