# create 2 mapviews on android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use multiple MapActivities/MapViews per Android application/process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379575/how-to-use-multiple-mapactivities-mapviews-per-android-application-process)

I need to create 2 `MapView`s on android; I can see that only one mapview is allowed per process, otherwise I get the `IllegalStateError`, but I need to have 2 map views in my app.

What am I trying to achieve?
I have a mapview on my primary(landing page) activity from which a user can choose a locations menu button which gives a popup window. From this resulting popupwindow I need to have a mapview for user to choose a point of interest and delete points amongst other things.

I need to keep the mapview on the underlying primary activity alive. I have already seen solutions where one is killed.

Comment: Temporarily killing the underlaying one is no solution?

Comment: Start migrating to Maps V2, which allows multiple maps per process. Besides, your desired functionality can be implemented with just one `MapView`, reused.

Comment: I need to keep the mapview in the underlying primary activity alive; so I am not sure how I can reuse the one mapview if its alive CommonsWare. For now I will go with the link by rds.